# In Apache Log4J, Is there a way to simply create multiple log files on the fly, rather than appending to one log file?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

I have a program, where I would like to be able to separate each single log-message into its own log file.

So if the class generates 10 `ERROR` logs and 10 `DEBUG` logs, within a single program execution, then that should create 20 log files , and they're names can ideally be something like :

```
logoutput1
logoutput2
logoutput3
..etc
```

And each log file just has a single line .

I'm working on an project where I'd like to implement some autonomic ability - the idea is that we can have a third , externally running program which can read in those log files(and then react based on them)

Is this possible with Log4j ?  how can this be done ?
thanks !

Comment: There is no way of creating new log file on log basis but you can do it by file size basis. Why do you need per log files?

Comment: May be you should use the RollingFileAppender and set the MaxFileSize property to a small value and MaxBackupIndex to a very high value !! . But why do you need this?

Comment: You may wish to read [What is the XY problem?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377) to clarify the purpose here….

Comment: @NipunTalukdar - I aiming for some kind of "autonomic" ability, whereby we can keep track of a program dynamically

Comment: @Eranda - I'm working on an project where I'd like to implement some autonomic ability - the idea is that we can have a third , externally running program which can read in those log files(and  then react based on them).  So imagine that we might say "If the log says 'FATAL' then email user1234" , or something similar

Comment: @NipunTalukdar - Please see note above to Eranda

Comment: @NipunTalukdar - Ah, Ok! I see what you mean with RollingFileAppender and MaxFileSize   - thanks !!!!

Comment: You can change your log4j properties in your program. change the file name each time before invoking the logger .

http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-change-my-log4j-settings-while-my-web-application-is-running.html

Comment: @JishnuPrathap-  May you elaborate little more please ? not sure what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can use the RoutingAppender. See this question for details: [Log4j2: Dynamic creation of log files for multiple logs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19052070/1446916)

Answer (score 4):

Write your own Log File Appender and create a new file every time when it attempts to write some log. The following piece of code might help you.

```
public class SingleLogMsgFileAppender extends FileAppender {

    private String file = null;

    private static long fileNo;

    public SingleLogMsgFileAppender() {
        super();
        fileNo = 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void subAppend(LoggingEvent event) {
        createNewFile(true);
        synchronized (this) {
            super.subAppend(event);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setFile(String file) {
        this.file = file;
        createNewFile(false);
    }

    public void createNewFile(boolean incrementFileNo) {
        try {
            String fileName = file + "testlogfile." + fileNo + ".log";
            super.setFile(fileName);
            super.activateOptions();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (incrementFileNo) {
            fileNo++;
        }
    }

}
```

and here is the log4j configuration file

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <appender name="CustomAppender" class="loga.randd.threads.log4j.SingleLogMsgFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="log/" />
        <param name="Append" value="true" />
        <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d{MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm_ss}%m%n" />
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="CustomAppender" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: So can you show me (by comments) where in your code, it handles the situation of making a new log file for every log message ? i'm not sure I see it

Comment: is this log4j2 ... or log4j-1.2 ?

Comment: createNewFile(..) is the method where the new file is created. the subAppend(..) method will be invoked every time when you attempt to write some logs. I have overridden subAppend() in my appender and invoked createNewFile() from it.