# How to resolve this error with RoutingAppender in Log4J - "AuditLogger cannot be located"?

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm getting the following error when I run my Log4j code :

```
2015-07-04 19:08:04,385 ERROR Appender AuditLogger cannot be located. Route ignored
```

I'm trying to use the `RoutingAppender` (I learned about it [from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19052070/log4j2-dynamic-creation-of-log-files-for-multiple-logs) ). 
My log4j config files looks like this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">

  <Appenders>

    <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
      <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </Console>

    <File name="MyFile" fileName="OutputLogFile.log" immediateFlush="false" append="false">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
    </File>


    <Routing name="Routing">
      <Routes pattern="$${sd:type}">
        <Route>
          <RollingFile name="Rolling-${sd:type}" fileName="${sd:type}.log"
                       filePattern="${sd:type}.%i.log.gz">
            <PatternLayout>
              <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500" />
          </RollingFile>
        </Route>
        <Route ref="AuditLogger" key="Audit"/>
      </Routes>
    </Routing>

  </Appenders>

  <Loggers>
    <Root level="all">
      <Appender-Ref ref="Console"/>
      <Appender-Ref ref="MyFile"/>  <!-- added_in now -->

    </Root>


  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And my code is just a simple client/server pair (with some `logger.debug("xyz")` code spread throughout) .

thanks

Comment: What should `AuditLogger` be referencing?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - I'm not really sure how that part works.  I think there's a "FlumeAppender" that I read about ?

Comment: I left out this code  `<Flume name="AuditLogger" compress="true">
      <Agent host="192.168.10.101" port="8800"/>
      <Agent host="192.168.10.102" port="8800"/>
      <RFC5424Layout enterpriseNumber="18060" includeMDC="true" appName="MyApp"/>
    </Flume>`