# How to correctly use RoutingAppender in log4j2 programmatically?

Tags: java, logging, log4j2

I am creating a log4j2 logger programmatically and adding appenders to it.

I want the logger to write the messages in two different locations / files according to some parameter/criteria.

For this I found that RoutingAppender can be good option to route the messages in different locations.

And for the criteria with the help of which I want to route messages, I am using Marker as used in [How to create multiple log file programatically in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336225/how-to-create-multiple-log-file-programatically-in-log4j2)

But I am enable to manage it properly.Below is my code snippet for reference :

```
public class Log4j2TestApplication {

private static final Marker MARKER1 = MarkerManager.getMarker("MARKER1");

private static final Marker MARKER2 = MarkerManager.getMarker("MARKER2");

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String loggerName = "demoLogger";
    final ConfigurationBuilder<BuiltConfiguration> builder = ConfigurationBuilderFactory.newConfigurationBuilder();

    final LoggerComponentBuilder loggerComp = builder.newLogger(loggerName, Level.ALL).addAttribute("additivity",
            false);

    builder.add(loggerComp);
    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
    LoggerContext ctx = Configurator.initialize(builder.build());
    ctx.start(configuration);
    ctx.updateLoggers(configuration);
    Logger logger = ctx.getLogger(loggerName);
    Appender csvAppender = createCsvAppender(configuration);
    Appender textAppender = createTextAppender(configuration);
    csvAppender.start();
    textAppender.start();
    logger.addAppender(csvAppender);
    logger.addAppender(textAppender);
    Appender routingAppender = createRoutingAppender(configuration, textAppender, csvAppender);
    routingAppender.start();
    logger.addAppender(routingAppender);
    logger.error(MARKER1, "the text message", "testing parameter");
    logger.error(MARKER2, "the csv message", "testing parameter");
    csvAppender.stop();
    textAppender.stop();
    routingAppender.stop();
}

private static Appender createCsvAppender(final Configuration config) {

    return RollingFileAppender.newBuilder().setConfiguration(config).setName("csvAppender")
            .withFileName("TestFile.csv").withFilePattern("TestFile.csv")
            .withPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("100M"))
            .withStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy.newBuilder().withConfig(config).build()).withImmediateFlush(true)
            .setFilter(ThresholdFilter.createFilter(Level.ALL, Result.ACCEPT, Result.DENY)).setLayout(getCsvLayout(config))
            .build();
}

private static Layout<String> getCsvLayout(final Configuration config) {

    return new CsvParameterLayout(config, StandardCharsets.UTF_8, CSVFormat.DEFAULT.withDelimiter(','),
            "column1;column2\n", null);
}

private static Appender createTextAppender(final Configuration config) {

    return RollingFileAppender.newBuilder().setConfiguration(config).setName("txtAppender")
            .withFileName("TestFile.txt").withFilePattern("TestFile.txt")
            .withPolicy(SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy.createPolicy("100M"))
            .withStrategy(DefaultRolloverStrategy.newBuilder().withConfig(config).build()).withImmediateFlush(true)
            .setFilter(ThresholdFilter.createFilter(Level.ALL, Result.ACCEPT, Result.DENY)).setLayout(getTextLayout(config, "header\n"))
            .build();
}

private static Layout<String> getTextLayout(final Configuration config, final String header) {
    return PatternLayout.newBuilder().withConfiguration(config).withCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
            .withPattern("[%d][%-5.-5p]").withHeader(header).build();
}

private static Appender createRoutingAppender(final Configuration config, Appender appender1, Appender appender2) {

    Route[] routeArray = new Route[2];
    routeArray[0] = Route.createRoute(appender1.getName(), "MARKER1", null);
    routeArray[1] = Route.createRoute(appender2.getName(), "MARKER2", null);
    Routes routes = Routes.newBuilder().withRoutes(routeArray).withPattern("marker").build();
    Appender routingAppender = RoutingAppender.newBuilder().setName("routingAppender").setConfiguration(config)
            .withRoutes(routes).build();

    return routingAppender;
    }
}
```

I have referenced below links also but I could not find the accurate way of RoutingAppender programmatically.

[Is there a way to Route logs based on Marker with the RoutingAppender in Log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30111754/is-there-a-way-to-route-logs-based-on-marker-with-the-routingappender-in-log4j2)

[Wildcard pattern for RoutingAppender of Log4j2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18279656/wildcard-pattern-for-routingappender-of-log4j2)

[How to create multiple log file programatically in log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46336225/how-to-create-multiple-log-file-programatically-in-log4j2)